# Why Posix File I/O is always blocking?

Tags: io, linux-kernel, posix

From man pages

> ```
> O_NONBLOCK or O_NDELAY  
>         This flag has no effect for regular files and block
>           devices; that is, I/O operations will (briefly) block when
>           device activity is required, regardless of whether O_NONBLOCK
>           is set.  Since O_NONBLOCK semantics might eventually be
>           implemented, applications should not depend upon blocking
>           behavior when specifying this flag for regular files and block
>           devices.
> ```

From [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469471/does-synchronous-i-o-keeps-thread-busy) I had following understanding of the io system.

```
             Device <-----> Kernel Buffers <----->  Process
```

So whenever Buffers are full (write) or empty (read), the corresponding command from the process can block or not depending on the flag above. Kernel interacting with the device is not blocking for the process. The kernel might or might not be using DMA for communication with the device.

But looks like my understanding is wrong as I can't see why the regular file descriptors can't be non-blocking. Could somebody help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Blocking" is defined as waiting for a file to become readable or writable.

Regular files are *always* readable and/or writable; in other words, it is always possible to try to *start* the read/write operation without having to wait for some external event:

- when reading, the kernel already knows if there are more bytes in the file (if the end of the file has been reached, it is not possible to block to wait for some other process to append more bytes);
- when writing, the kernel already knows if there is enough space on the disk to write something (if the disk is full, it is not possible to block to wait for some other process to delete some data to free up space).

Comment: That was exactly my thought, but this line confuses me._I/O operations will (briefly) block when device activity is required_. Why would a file will be (briefly ) waiting  to get ready?

Comment: That explanation uses a different definition of the word "block", i.e., from the point of view of the read()/write() interface, the file is always "ready".

Comment: you have been very helpful. One last follow up. what is the definition being used for `block` here?

Comment: "some time elapses, and the kernel does not return to your program"

Comment: Does this means that `read()` will not return until kernel gets the byte from the disk?

Comment: In blocking mode, `read()` returns at least one byte, or an error, or end-of-file.

Comment: Well, you could say `read()` returns exactly the same types of things in _non-blocking_ mode as it does in _blocking_ mode, except that the error value `EAGAIN` (or `EWOULDBLOCK` on some POSIX systems) is not a "real" error.